# R custom color theme in levelplot

Tags: r, color-ramp

R

```
range(diffRain)
[1] -2.59  7.59
```

How can I code a color ramp following ways?

```
red color ramp less than 0.0
blue color ramp greater than 0.0
```

This is a part of my code.

```
myTheme <- modifyList(custom.theme(region=brewer.pal(8, 'RdBu')),
                                   list(
                                     strip.background=list(col='gray'),
                                     panel.background=list(col='gray')))

levelplot(diffRain ~ month * year,par.settings=myTheme,panel = myPanel,
        at=pretty(c(minR, maxR), n=8),
        xlab = "month\n San Jose Long-Term(1922-2012) Avg. Monthly Rainfall in inches",
        main = "Monthly rainfall - Long-Term Avg. Monthly Rainfall\n 1922-2012",
        sub =paste(names(MonthAvgRain.Longterm),"\n",MonthAvgRain.Longterm, sep=""))

trellis.focus("legend", side="right", clipp.off=TRUE, highlight=FALSE)
grid.text(expression(inches), 0.2, 0, hjust=0.5, vjust=1)
trellis.unfocus()
```

[image]

Comment: What are you going to do with this colour ramp once you've go it? Different plot functions have different ways of mapping values to colours. `ggplot2` uses its own `scales` concept, base graphics uses a fixed palette (usually) and so on...

Answer (score 5):

You should have a look at http://colorbrewer2.org/, and diverging color schemes therein. It can be imported into R using `brewer.pal` from the **RColorBrewer** package.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
cols <- brewer.pal(11, "RdBu")
```

Or, for more than the default maximum of 11 colors, use `colorRampPalette`.

```
cols <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "RdBu"))
```

Comment: Ok I will try it with ggplot2.